# Creating default object from empty value Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Using yii2 trying make success callback for payments. Callback work, but i need make changes for order. In my common/congig/main.php:

```
'successCallback' => function($invoice) {
    $order = \common\models\Checkout::findOne($invoice->order_id);
    $order->payment_status = 1;
    $order->update();
}
```

$invoice->order_id; receives current order id, i need change payment status for checkout model.

**Update:**

can I somehow run it recursively? for example, if I have several records with one ID?

Comment: What's not working? your code seems to be ok

Comment: error Creating default object from empty value in line $order->payment_status = 1;

Comment: Can you tell me what's the  Checkout's ID column in the database so I can give you an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `findOne()` requires the name of the column to compare the value, in this case, the Checkout's ID column.

**Assuming** it's `order_id` like in invoice table.

The code will be like this:

```
'successCallback' => function($invoice) {
    $order = \common\models\Checkout::findOne(['order_id' => $invoice->order_id]);
    $order->payment_status = 1;
    $order->update();
}
```

Replace 'order_id' with the checkout's id column if it has a different name.

**Update**
To update multiple records you could do something like this:

```
'successCallback' => function($invoice) {
    \common\models\Checkout::updateAll(['payment_status'=>1],['order_id' => $invoice->order_id]);
}
```

Make a DB backup before testing this code.

Comment: Ur solution give error too Creating default object from empty value

Comment: What's the name of the checkout column?  How are you using the success callback? what does invoice get as value?

Comment: I think I understood, I had a wrong selection from the database, can I somehow run it recursively? for example, if I have several records with one ID?

Comment: It if helps, remember to mark the answer. If you have multiple records you can use updateAll, i can update the answer by having the column name and if you update the question

Comment: updated answer.